# Scale rotated rectangle to fit inside bounding box

Tags: javascript, math, rotation

So I have resize functionality which works on non-rotated rectangles, but I need to make it work on rotated ones too.. So my idea is to resize the bounding box of a rotated rectangle and then fit the rotated rectangle inside.. Unfortunately, I can't figure it out.. Here are the variables which I have:

```
cW = currentRotatedRectangleWidth
cH = currentRotatedRectangleHeight
rad = angleOfRotation
cBW = currentRotatedRectangleBoundingWidth
cBW = Math.abs(cH * Math.sin(rad)) + Math.abs(cW * Math.cos(rad))
cBH = currentRotatedRectangleBoundingHeight
cBH = Math.abs(cH * Math.sin(rad)) + Math.abs(cW * Math.cos(rad))
nBW = newBoundingWidth
nBH = newBoundingHeight
dx = differenceWidth = (cBW - cW) / 2
dy = differenceHeight = (cBH - cH) / 2
```

[image]

So I need to fit the rotated rectangle into the bounding box with dimensions nBW * nBH

Answer (score 1):

I assume that nBW / nBH ratio may differ from ideal one. So you have to choose minimal value from Vertical/Horizontal coefficients to fit rotated rectangle properly.

```
 CoeffH = nbW / cBW
 CoeffV = nbH / cBH
 Coeff = Min(CoeffH, CoeffV)
```

Now multiply linear sizes by Coeff.

Comment: It definitely should work. How do you apply this approach and what's wrong?

Comment: I had done a mistake, now it's working perfectly :) thanks